# Android Accessibility Notifications for Google Talk

Tags: android, notifications, accessibility, google-talk

I'm working on an accessibility app on android that uses notification events. However, it only registers notifications for Google Talk when users send outgoing messages, and seems not to catch notifications for incoming messages. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Different Intent broadcasts perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you catch outgoing notifications it means the service is working.

Try logging any event arriving in onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent paramAccessibilityEvent)

Make sure status bar notifications are enabled in Google Talk, of course.